# How to add a spinner icon during import in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a spreadsheet importer and would like to display some kind of icon while the data is loading. The submit button as it is is:

```
<%= f.submit "Import", :class => 'btn btn-primary'%>
```

I tried using bootstrap, but it does not seem to work, that code looked like:

```
<button type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary start"
        id="btnStartUploads"
        data-loading-text="<i class='icon-spinner icon-spin icon-large'></i> ">
    <i class="icon-upload icon-large"></i>
    <span><%= f.submit "Import"%>Import</span>
</button>
```

Comment: I like Ladda for button spinners.  https://github.com/hakimel/Ladda

Comment: According to Bootstrap docs the data-loading-text feature is deprecated since v3.3.5 and will be removed in v4. Did you try to use JQuery to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this. I guess this should work.

```
<%= f.submit "<i class="icon-upload icon-large"></i><span>Import</span>".html_safe, class: 'btn btn-primary start', id: id="btnStartUploads", "data-loading-text" => 'icon-spinner icon-spin icon-large' %>
```